# Need to get referer during local debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: json, visual-studio-2015, arcgis

I'm trying to generate a token (well, this does generate a token but it doesn't work currently) for ArcGIS Online. The only issue is, I need to set the referer property correctly.

Currently my JSON string is:

```
string Data = "f=json&request=gettoken&username=<<MY_USER_NAME>>&password=<<MY_PASSWORD>>&referer=http://localhost:12345/";
```

(where 12345 is a made-up number - I have entered the one that is used but, whilst that does return a token, it doesn't work)

Is there any way I can find out the referer in Chrome, or would I have to try Fiddler or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, I found it at https://superuser.com/questions/231540/how-can-i-see-a-pages-referrer-in-chrome

For those interested, in Chrome:

> 1. In the Developer Tools, go to the Network view (if it wasn't open when you loaded the page, you'll need to reload to get it populated).
> 2. Click on the main page request -- it should be at the top of the list.
> 3. When you click, the right pane will probably show the HTML for it.
> 4. Click on the "Headers" tab on the right side. The Referer is shown in the list of Request Headers.

It's still not working as I want though.